# Is this geometric Interpretation of $Q^T$ being orthonormal if $Q$ is orthonormal valid?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, inverse, orthonormal, transpose

I was reading the book - Linear Algebra and its Applications, when I saw -

> Remark 2. 
>   Since $Q^T = Q^{-1}$, we also have $QQ^T = I$. When Q comes before $Q^T$, multiplication
>   takes the inner products of the rows of Q. (For $Q^TQ$ it was the columns.)
>   Since the result is again the identity matrix, we come to a surprising conclusion: **The
>   rows of a square matrix are orthonormal whenever the columns are**. The rows point
>   in completely different directions from the columns, and I don’t see geometrically why
>   they are forced to be orthonormal—but they are.

I was wondering if the following geometric interpretation is valid.

As we already know geometrically, an orthogonal matrix Q is the product of a rotation (through say  θ) and a reflection.
**When Q is a square matrix**, then $Q^T$ ( Q transpose)  will be $Q^{-1}$ (Q inverse). And therefore Q^T ( Q transpose) can be thought
of geometrically as the undoing of Q, i.e. rotation about -θ and a repeated reflection about the same axis.
Thus operating $QQ^T$ is same as operating $Q^TQ$,
 as we are doing (rotation reflection) then (opposite rotation and reflection) -  $QQ^T$
or (opposite rotation and reflection) and then (rotation reflection) - $Q^TQ$,

Both of which do nothing to the vector (being operated on). ie they are the identity matrix.

From the above as we see that  $Q^T$ ( Q transpose) can be thought of geometrically as the undoing of Q, a product of a rotation and a reflection. 
we can say that the rows are also orthonormal (as they form the columns of Q^T).

Comment: A matrix is orthogonal if and only if its columns form an orthonormal basis, which is the same as saying that $Q^T=Q^{-1}$. Let $R=Q^T$. Then $R^T=Q=(Q^T)^{-1}=R^{-1}$. So $R$ is orthogonal. Where is the problem?

Comment: @egreg the problem is that you implicitly use the two-sidedness of matrix inverses, which (I find, anyway) is not intuition-friendly. Consider, for example, why it is possible for a matrix to have *orthogonal* columns without having orthogonal rows. The key here is to make that two-sidedness of the inverse understandable, apparently.

Comment: @egreg I don't have a problem understanding why both the rows as well as the columns are orthonormal mathematically. but GIlbert Strang in his book (check out the extract I posted) has said he couldn't see geometrically why the rows are forced to be orthonormal given the columns were. I wanted to just confirm if my geometric explanation had any fallacies.

Comment: @Shikamaru you have the right idea. Namely: with linear maps in finite-dimensional spaces, if $AB$ is the identity map, then $BA$ must also be the identity map. Of course, then, this is true for orthogonal maps, which happen to be rotations/reflections.

Comment: @Shikamaru I would say, however, that your explanation is not a "geometric" one in the sense that Strang is going for. That is, if we have a set of $n$ row-vectors in $n$-dimensional space, why should the resulting columns be orthonormal as well? To see this, we would want a geometric way to go directly from $n$ row-arrows to $n$ column-arrows.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks, I knew I must have missed something, what I had explained was the geometric interpretation of both matrices itself rather than the vectors which are created from the rows and columns. (those vectors are what you referred to as row/column arrows right?). could you tell me any example where I can see an actual geometric explanation involving such row/column arrows in action?

Comment: @Aditya for example, the Gram Schmidt process is pretty easy to think in terms of the vectors themselves, and geometrically.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Oh ok I got it, thanks.